# Node: ShellJS not working with command line tools

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell

If I execute `shell.exec('http')` I get the help for httpie, a request library I use. However if I add an argument, like seen below, shelljs never calls the callback.

```
var shell = require('shelljs');

shell.exec('http http://www.example.com/', {async: true, silent: false}, function(data){
  console.log(data);
})
```

The above example DOES work if I use `curl` instead of `http`. Any ideas why its not working with `http`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ignore-stdin` option

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.exec('http --ignore-stdin http://www.example.com/', {async: true, silent: false}, function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

The `--ignore-stdin` option prevents HTTPie from reading data from stdin, which is usually not desirable during non-interactive invocations.

You can read more in the Scripting section of [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie)